# How to add a whitespace in a random array?

Tags: ruby, string

Today I wanted to learn Ruby and started making a simple program, which generates a random string and then sorts it. The code for the random string is not mine, I've just googled it:

```
def random_string
 a = ("a".."z")
 b = (0..9)
 c = a.to_a + b.to_a
 key = c.shuffle[0, 8].join
end
```

I understand most of this method, and my question is, what do I need to add in order to generate a string with a chance of getting a whitespace? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `c = a.to_a + b.to_a` to `c = a.to_a + b.to_a + [' ']`

Comment: @GuillermoMora in what way didn't it work? remember not every random string will include a space but if you call `random_string` a few times you should get a value returned that includes at least one space.

Comment: @mikej Ok, I don't know what I did yesterday, but today I've just copy your code and it works perfectly ._. Thank you so much!